# Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class CustomUserAdmin error in admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-custom-user

I am getting this error even though I have already removed and migrated again. Initially, I added as extra boolean field is_vehicle_owner after Abstracting a Usermodel and then it was removed later. But i get this error.
Any help will be appreciated.

```
FieldError at /admin/accounts/customuser/1/change/
Unknown field(s) (is_vehicle_owner) specified for CustomUser. Check 
fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class CustomUserAdmin.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/accounts/customuser/1/change/
Django Version: 3.1.4
Exception Type: FieldError
Exception Value:    
Unknown field(s) (is_vehicle_owner) specified for CustomUser. Check 
fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class CustomUserAdmin.
Exception Location:  
C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py, line 711, in get_form
Python Executable:   
C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.0
Python Path:    
['E:\\Django\\projects\\carpool',
'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python39.zip',
'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs',
'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib',
'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39',
'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site- 
packages']
Server time:    Thu, 18 Mar 2021 18:28:58 +0000
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py, line 709, in get_form
        return modelform_factory(self.model, **defaults) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
packages\django\forms\models.py, line 555, in modelform_factory
return type(form)(class_name, (form,), form_class_attrs) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
packages\django\forms\models.py, line 268, in __new__
            raise FieldError(message) …
▶ Local vars
During handling of the above exception (Unknown field(s) (is_vehicle_owner) 
 specified for CustomUser), another exception occurred:
 C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py, line 47, in inner
            response = get_response(request) …
```

Comment: The error says _"Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class CustomUserAdmin."_ most likely you had specified the field somewhere in your models admin.

Comment: Thanks @abdul-aziz-barkat I was panicking a lot and didn't noticed that error